# Inject a child provider to the parent in angular?

Tags: angular, routes, provider

I would like to add a feature in a parent component using the activated child's provider.

I've got two children like so :

`Child1.module.ts`

```
  providers: [
    { provide: Service,  useClass: Service1},
  ],
```

`Child2.module.ts`

```
  providers: [
    { provide: Service,  useClass: Service2},
  ],
```

Now, in the parent module, i want to provide Service1 or Service2 depending on which child is activated, maybe with a `provide:Service, useFactory: (route: ActivatedRoute)` or something ?

Edit :

Here a quick picture of the idea :
[image]

Thanks !

Comment: Can you explain bit more about structure of your problem?

Comment: Just add a quick picture :)